# Transpile ES6 Generators with Babel in the browser

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-cli

I am able to transpile ES6 with babel but when I tried to test generators, I got this exception. `Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

I looked around and found out that I have to add bable-generator and runtime plugins. I added them as you can see from package.json but still getting this error.

I am running babel cli "npm run watch" which compiles my code and I can run it in the browser. I have a feeling that I am missing a step :)

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d output",
    "watch": "babel src --watch -d output"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6"
  }
}

{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Comment: Do you also load the Babel polyfill in your source?

Comment: @robertklep, nope that was the issue :). Thank you.

Comment: You'd generally use either `babel-polyfill` or `babel-runtime` but not both FYI. You've got `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` in your package, but haven't enabled it in your `.babelrc`, so doing that would also fix this issue.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Got it. I am running this in the browser. How would I enable babel-runtime in the .babelrc to run in the browser. Tried it earlier and it added bunch of requires to the transpiled file, which the browser doesn't recognize.

Comment: `babel-runtime` is a module, so for it to work in the browser, you'd have to use Babel via Browserify.